# storm-kafka-client spout consume message at different speed for different partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a storm cluster of 5 nodes and a kafka cluster installed on the same nodes.

- storm version: 1.2.1
- kafka version: 1.1.0

I also have a kafka topic of 10 partitions.

Now, i want to consume this topic's data and process it by storm. But the message consume speed is really strange.

For test reason, my storm topology have only one component - kafka spout, and i always set kafka spout parallelism of 10, so that one partition will be read by only one thread.

When i run this topology on just **1 worker**, **all partitions** will be read quickly and the lag is almost the same.(very small) 
When i run this topology on **2 workers**, **5 partitions** will be read quickly, but the other **5 partitions** will be read very slowly.
When i run this topology on **3 or 4 workers**, **7 partitions** will be read quickly and the other **3 partitions** will be read very slowly.
When i run this topology on more than **5 workers**, **8 partitions** will be read quickly and the other **2 partitions** will be read slowly.

Another strange thing is, when i use a **different consumer group id** when configure kafka spout, the test result may be different.
For example, when i use a specific group id and run topology on **5 workers**, only **2 partitions** can be read quickly. Just the opposite of the test using another group id.

I have written a simple java app that call High-level kafka jave api. I run it on each of the 5 storm node and find it can consume data very quickly for every partition. So the network issue can be excluded.

Has anyone met the same problem before? Or has any idea of what may cause such strange problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen or heard of this behavior before. Could you post your topology? The code where you interact with TopologyBuilder will probably be enough.